# Cannot find module 'swiper/types' Angular

Tags: angular, node-modules, swiper.js, ngx-swiper-wrapper

I tried to follow https://swiperjs.com/angular but I got this error,
I also installed npm i @types/swiper but still the same error .
Here is the error

> ERROR in
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:5:117 -
> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'swiper/types' or its corresponding
> type declarations.
>
> 5 import { SwiperOptions, SwiperEvents, NavigationOptions,
> PaginationOptions, ScrollbarOptions, VirtualOptions } from
> 'swiper/types';

my app module

```
import { SwiperModule } from 'swiper/angular';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule ,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SwiperModule
  ],
```

and in my global style, I added

```
@import "~@angular/material/theming";
@import '~swiper/swiper-bundle';
```

Comment: Have you tried to re-build the project after importing the module?

Comment: yeeah bro the same problem

Answer (score 2):

You have to reduce the version of swiper js to run.
example: npm i swiper@8.4.6

Answer (score 1):

For Ionic folks, when I installed using the command npm i swiper@latest, it installed v10.3.1. I got this error and then followed dbgupta's advice and downgraded from the latest v10 to the last version of v9. using the command: npm i swiper@9.4.1 and now I am not getting this error anymore in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps that I follow whenever I get these kind of errors.

1. Re-build the project after importing the module, JIT sometimes fails
2. Make sure the package was installed properly (The documentation says to install it with `npm i swiper`, try to use it instead of `npm i @types/swiper`, might work)
3. Make sure the path from import exists and it points to a file
4. Don't add imports manually, unless there is a strong reason for that. I use extensions like Auto-Import for VSCode which does the importing for me, I just have to write 'SwiperModule', and the import appears by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Swiper needs to be compatible with the typescript version as well.
If you're using Angular@16, please check that you use typescript version 5+ in package.json.

This was the issue in my case.